# What scope does Randomize function have?

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

I recentlly began to use Randomize function to reset randoms and I can't understand exactlly what it does because ot appears to afect all of the threads I'm running at a time instead of I'm using new random() at it appears it only affects one thread.

My point is that I can't understand the scope of Randomize sentence.It seems it has a system scope but I can't understand the reason because the msdn documentation tells me this about randomize:
Randomize uses Number to initialize the Rnd function's random-number generator, giving it a new seed value

Comment: Please show some code. Are you by any chance `new` ing Random in a loop?

Comment: I think he's refering to the VB6 compatibility Rnd and Randomize functions, not to the Random object

Comment: The Net Random class is easier to use than the old legacy VB functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Basically the randomize function changes the seed. This means that it changes the randomization. Doing this makes it truely random, whereas if you don't change the seed, you'll get the same 'pattern' of randomness every time.